# Cannot Delete Account - Where do merge validation rules live?

Tags: opportunity, account, validation-rule, merge, setup

When I try to merge two accounts that have sales opportunities, I get the following validation exception:

> Cannot Delete Account Sales Opportunities Exist

Based on the dearth of Google hits for that term, I'm assuming this is a custom validation rule that we've set up on Salesforce at some point.

The only problem is that I can't find out where it lives. I've looked in...

- Duplicate rules - nothing
- Matching rules - only the 3 standard rules, none active
- Duplicate Record Set Validation Rules - nada
- Duplicate Record Item Validation Rules - zilch
- Account Validation Rules - diddly squat
- Account triggers - only those associated with installed apps

I may have forgotten other places I've looked and been disappointed.

Can anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: Have you looked at triggers?

Comment: @SFDCNeuf Yep, the only ones there are managed triggers associated with installed apps.

Comment: Just confirming did you check Account specific triggers/ Opportunity triggers too?

Comment: Yeah `Validation Rules` cannot fire on delete. If you set a lookup as required on the child object you might see some such error...check for custom `Lookup` relationships from `Opportunity` to `Account`.

Comment: May be lookup validation rules..

Comment: @AdrianLarson This did it! It turns out that we have an app with a custom object called a "Sales Opportunity". I can't see the exact lookup implementation (it's a managed object), but I'm betting it's in here somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I've cornered this error to a lookup to a custom object managed by an app we have installed.

The confusion was caused by the fact that this custom object is called a "Sales Opportunity". When I read the exception ("*Cannot Delete Account Sales Opportunities Exist*") I assumed it was referring to a standard SF Opportunity object, which was a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've seen a validation which didn't come from `Apex` that would prevent deletion is when a `Lookup Relationship` is marked as required. Notice that when you mark it as required, it forces you to select the option:

> Don't allow deletion of the lookup record that's part of a lookup relationship.

[image: Lookup Required]